# FallbackResource Directive gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using WAMP.I have a project whose directory structure is as follows:

```
my_project/
    -folder_1
    -folder_2
    -404.php
    -.htaccess
    -router.php
    -index.php
    -file_1.php
    -file_2.php
```

Now the plan is to redirect all non-matching page request to 'router.php'. From this `router.php` I would like to redirect the request to appropriate php pages.

In order to direct all non-matching incoming requests to `router.php`, I have written the following line in the .htaccess file. However, when I click on an invalid/non-matching hyperlink, instead of taking me to `router.php` page it shows me '500 Internal Server Error'.

```
FallbackResource router.php
```

Please advise what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You need to check the apache error logs for a more specific error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because that it can't find the `router.php` and thus falls into a recursion. If you check your error logs, you'll probably find something along the lines of:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Try this instead:

```
FallbackResource /router.php #Note the leading slash.
```

If the `my_project/` directory is not your document root and you have to access it like `localhost/my_project`, you need to mention the directory hierarchy as well:

```
FallbackResource /my_project/router.php
```

So, if it's `localhost/foo/bar/my_project`, it'd be:

```
FallbackResource /foo/bar/my_project/router.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I just checked the error log and it just says what you have mentioned above.However when i use the leading slash then it takes me to-- believe or not  to Wampservers Homepage :(. Am i missing something??

Comment: It's probably because `my_project/` directory is not your webserver root and you have to access it like `localhost/my_project`. In this case, use `/my_project/router.php`.

Comment: Thanks @sepher.It now works but all the CSS is messed up.Why is that & whats need to done to correct?Correct some path somewhere???

Comment: Where are your CSS files? and what do you exactly mean by *`messed up`*? What errors are you encountering?

Comment: ->localhost/my_project/css/cssfikes.css. by 'messed up' i meant to say that all the css styling is gone.image not showing etc.

Comment: Is the css file accessible in your browser? what do you get when opening `http://localhost/my_project/css/cssfikes.css` in your browser?